# Compare data across rows in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to solve the following problem in MS Excel:

> There are two columns of data, one for types of food and one for how many of them are (in an inventory, say). I want a SINGLE formula that will return FALSE if there is a row that goes "steak, [# > 0]" and TRUE otherwise. Note that each type of food can appear more than one time (or not at all) in the list.

For examples: (separating the rows by ","):

> Banana, 1
>
> Steak, 0
>
> Steak, 0
>
> Steak, 0

---> Returns TRUE (all the steaks have a 0 next to them)

> Banana, 1
>
> Steak, 0
>
> Steak, 1
>
> Steak, 0

---> Returns  FALSE (the third row has steak and then a positive number)

> Banana, 1
>
> Tomato, 0
>
> Cheese, 1
>
> Milk, 0

---> returns TRUE (this is vacuously true, there's no "steak" for there to be more than 0 of).

Note that I need to do this in a single formula, ideally. I could create an auxiliary column in some other sheet, do the logical check row-wise, and then AND all those together, but that would be a huge headache (i have to do this type of construction many times in the sheet across many different types of data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using a `SUM()` function to perform `Boolean` Logic Operation to return `TRUE` & `FALSE`'s

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM((A1="Steak")*(B1>0))=0
```

---

Using one single dynamic array formula that spills for the whole array:

```
=MAP(A1:A7,B1:B7,LAMBDA(α,δ,SUM((α="Steak")*(δ>0))=0))
```

---

**Note:** If using `Excel 2010` then change the `SUM()` in first method to `SUMPRODUCT()` even `SUM()` function works but it needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Comment: Awesome!! this works perfectly. Can you explain your note at the bottom though? (I'm using a business license of excel for work and am not familiar with the sum product formula)

Comment: @zz20s sure thing. Here is what it does. It takes two arrays and does a matrix multiplications to get the sum. So first it creates an array with `(A1:A7="Steak")` where the type is `Steak` which returns `TRUE` i.e. `1` else `0`, and then it does the same with the quantity as well to see whether its greater than `#>=0` or not returns the same as `1` & `0` both sum of the product of these arrays is greater than 0, it means there’s a `Steak` and a `+ve` quantity hence returns `FALSE` else returns `TRUE`

Comment: Why do you need ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: Because it creates an array formula and does a multiple calculations all at once, if you are using `Excel 2010` then will require to hit the same, else not, in `Modern Versions` it doesnt require. Here is a **[MSFT_Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:~:text=Dynamic%20array%20formulas%2C%20whether%20they%E2%80%99re%20using%20existing%20functions,output%20range%2C%20then%20confirming%20the%20formula%20with%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BEnter.)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all numbers are zero or more (no negatives), you could count all the steaks, then take away all the steak = 0, leaving the number of steak = [>0], then check if the result is >0. For example:

```
=(COUNTIF(A1:A999,"Steak*")-COUNTIF(A1:A999,"Steak, 0"))>0
```

If numbers less than zero are possible, the above counts the non-zero ones. You could easily adapt it to also deduct the count of the pattern "Steak, -*" to remove these too.